# How to store and add horizontal frames within a scrollable frame using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, scroll, frame

[image: design I am aiming for]

I am trying to implement a design like this, where you have a canvas inside a frame which is scrollable, so I can have alot of different entries in the frame. I have added the code I have currently. The listbox was simply a test and I will not be using the listbox. I basically need a way to store lots of horizontal frames within the scrollbar frame I think, that can hold a canvas to display the image, and some buttons/labels. The code I have currently means the scrollable frame window is very small so I need to know how to enlarge this and how to make it so I can store as many frames as I need within the scrollable one. Thank you

```
    customisationWindow = tk.Toplevel(mainWindow)
    customisationWindow.geometry("700x580")
    customisationWindow.title("DIY Store Quote System")
    tabControl = ttk.Notebook(customisationWindow)

    tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl, width=300)
    tab1.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
    tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
    tab3 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
    tab4 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
    tab5 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)

    tabControl.add(tab1, text='Select Wallpaper')
    tabControl.add(tab2, text='Select Colour')
    tabControl.add(tab3, text='Select Detailing')
    tabControl.add(tab4, text='Add Adhesive/Lining')
    tabControl.add(tab5, text='View Basket')
    tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
    createTab1(tab1)
    createTab2(tab2)
    createTab3(tab3)
    createTab4(tab4)
    createTab5(tab5)


def createTab5(tab):

    yourBasketLabel = Label(tab, text="Your Basket", bg="#94B3BD",
                        font=("Times New Roman", 14)).place(x=50, y=50)

    basketFrame = Frame(tab, width=550, height=400)
    basketFrame.place(x=50, y=70)
    basketCanvas = Canvas(basketFrame, width=550, height=400)
    basketCanvas.place(x=50, y=70)
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(basketCanvas)
    scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    
    mylist = Listbox(basketFrame, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    for line in range(100):
        mylist.insert(END, "This is line number " + str(line))

    mylist.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
    scrollbar.config(command=mylist.yview)


mainWindow = Tk()
mainFrame = Frame(mainWindow, bg="#94B3BD")
mainFrame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
verticalFrame = Frame(mainFrame, bg="#94B3BD")

mainWindow.geometry("500x200")

welcomeMessage = tk.Label(verticalFrame, text="Welcome to the DIY Store Quote System", background="#94B3BD",
                          pady=40, font=("Arial", 25)).pack()
startButton = tk.Button(verticalFrame, highlightbackground='#B1E4EC', text="Begin Customising Wallpaper",
                        font=("Arial", 25),
                        pady=20, command=open).pack()
verticalFrame.pack()

mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a scrollbar to the canvas and then add a frame into the canvas with `create_window`. You can then add more frames to `myList`.

```
def createTab5(tab):

    yourBasketLabel = Label(tab, text="Your Basket", bg="#94B3BD",
                        font=("Times New Roman", 14)).place(x=50, y=50)

    basketFrame = Frame(tab, width=550, height=400)
    basketFrame.place(x=50, y=70)
    basketCanvas = Canvas(basketFrame, width=550, height=400)
    basketCanvas.pack(fill = "both", expand = True, side = "left")
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(basketFrame, command = basketCanvas.yview)
    scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    basketCanvas.config(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
    basketCanvas.bind("<Configure>", resizeCanvas)
    myList = tk.Frame(basketCanvas)
    basketCanvas.create_window((4,4), window = myList, anchor = "nw")
    for line in range(100):
        frame = tk.Frame(myList)
        frame.pack()
        label = tk.Label(frame, text = "This is line number {}".format(str(line)))
        label.pack()
    scrollbar.config(command=basketCanvas.yview)

def resizeCanvas(event):
    canvas = event.widget
    canvas.update_idletasks()
    canvas.config(scrollregion = canvas.bbox("all"))
```

Comment: Thank you, you saved me!!! I appreciate this so much

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick:

```
import tkinter as tk

def addFrame(window, frames):
    frame = tk.Frame(window, width=50, height=50)
    label = tk.Label(frame, text = "New frame number {} wow!".format(len(frames)))
    label.pack()
    frame.pack()

    frames.append(frame)
    print("Those are all the frames:", frames)

my_frames = []

window = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(window, text = 'Add frame', command = lambda: addFrame(window, my_frames)) 
button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

- Every time you press a button new frame is created with it's unique label.
- All the frames are stored in the list `my_frames` for you to access.

Comment: Thank you!! This is brilliant and adding a button and storing them in a list is exactly what I needed to implement, amazing.